# How to run rm command on windows 10?

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

```
"build": "rm -rf ./build && mkdir ./build && ./node_modules/.bin/babel -d ./build ./src"
```

This is the command in package.json and it gives me an error saying:

```
rm is not recognized as internal or external command.
Invalid switch /build
```

Comment: Before I got a Mac, I did all of my command-line type development in the Git Bash which emulates a UNIX style terminal for your environment

Answer (score 23):

That script was written for the UNIX shell, which does not work on windows. The correct way to do this in a cross-platform way is to use [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) & [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp).

Also, the `./node_modules/.bin/babel` portion could be shortened to simply `babel` (`./node_modules/.bin/babel` doesn't work on windows IIRC).

Properly written, the script should be:

```
"build": "rimraf ./build && mkdirp ./build && babel -d ./build ./src"
```

For this script to work, you will have to install `rimraf` and `mkdirp`. You can do this by running:

```
npm install --save-dev rimraf mkdirp
```

The `--save-dev` flag will add `rimraf` and `mkdirp` to your `package.json`'s `devDependencies` section so that they will automatically be installed with future `npm install`s.

Answer (score 6):

Use `rd /s /q "folder name"` instead of `rm -rf "folder name"`

Answer (score 4):

In order to run bash commands on Windows you need to install Bash complied for Windows. Install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and add `bin` directory to you  `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 does not provide a UNIX shell by default. You'll need the appropriate UNIX utilities (such as rm) and a shell that supports the syntax you specified.

You have a few options:

- **Use the Windows 10 Bash Shell** - Recent versions of [Windows 10 now provide beta support](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) for running Ubuntu within Windows without requiring a virtual machine.
- **Use Cygwin for development** - [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) provides a shell of your choice and plenty of UNIX / Linux utilities.
- **Run a Virtual Machine with a Linux Guest** - There are many options for running  a VM on Windows. You can use Hyper-V, VirtualBox, or VMware Player. For a guest operating system, Ubuntu is a popular choice, but Fedora and Debian are also common alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Not to Bash, but in Windows you can use the built-in remove directory (rd) command:

```
RD /S /Q "folder-name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-wsl2
You will install a linux client for windows, and then instal node.js for that client and you can run rm commands easily